how to name a property title or description in a json schema
I have a json schema with properties named "description" and "title"
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "description": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "a description"
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "a title"
    }
  }
}

The schema validator in Webstorm gives two errors:
Incompatible Types: Required string, actual object.
How do I define this properties correctly? Or is it a bug in the schema validator?
